# Finding $a$ and $b$ such that $x^3-4ax^2-8bx-3+a+b$ has a triple root

Tags: polynomials, roots

$$P(x)=x^3-4ax^2-8bx-3+a+b$$

NOTE: a & b are both real and the solution is not necessarily unique

**So far i've done this:**

If $P(x)$ is a $3$rd degree polynomial and has a triple root, then it has the form:
$$
P(x)=(x-n)^3=x^3-3x^2 n+3xn^2-n^3.
$$
Then
$$
x^3-3x^2 n+3xn^2-n^3=x^3-4ax^2-8bx+(-3+a+b).
$$

And from this, I got three equations:

$$-3n=-4a$$
$$3n^2=-8b$$
$$-n^3=(-3+a+b)$$

I don't know what to do from here. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Are you sure about the coefficients of the polynomial? With those coefficients, I get one and only one solution ($a\approx1.042$ and $b\approx-0.724$), but I can compute it only by numerical methods.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. If $f(x) = (x-n)^3$, then $f'$ and $f''$ must also vanish at $x = n$. Try to use this fact.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I can get a cubic for $a$, namely $64a^3 - 18a^2 + 27a - 81 = 0 $, so one can apply the cubic root to get the exact answer, which Wolfram says is $\frac{3}{32} [ 1 - 3 \sqrt[3]{25} / \sqrt[3]{149 + 8 \sqrt{349} } + \sqrt[3]{5(149 + 8 \sqrt{349}) }  ] $. I do agree it's likely that the coefficients should be different.

Comment: I'm not getting where these cubics and specific solutions are coming from... Is the OP's approach of obtaining the three equations wrong?  Multiplying the first two together yields two equations in $a,b$ parameterized by $n^3$, which seems to allow for more than one solution set...

Comment: I'm also able to get the cubic equation for a and also, by multiplying the first two equations and substituting in the 3rd equation i get: $(8/3)ab=-3+a+b$ which suggests multiple solutions.

Comment: May I suggest the modification $p(x)=x^3-4ax^2-8bx-\frac 18+a+4b$ instead. It removes nothing to the exercise, but at least the final value of $a$ is unique and simple, i.e $\frac 38$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x−k)^3=x3−4ax^2+(−8b)x−(3−a−b)$

$⟹x^3−(3k)x^2+(3k^2)x−k^3=x^3−4ax^2+(−8b)x−(3−a−b)$
$⟹x^3−(3k)x^2+(3k^2)x−k^3=x^3−4ax^2+(−8b)x−(3−a−b)$

Comparing like terms

$3k=4a$
$⟹a=3k/4 $

$3k^2=−8b$
$⟹b=−3k^2/8$

$k^3=3−a−b$
$⟹k^3=3−3k/4+3k^2/8$
$⟹8k^3−3k^2+6k−24=0 $

Solving this gives $k≈1.38935$

$a≈1.04201$
$b≈−0.723859$

Answer (score 2):

Doing the same as @Soumya Patel, the cubic equation
$$8k^3−3k^2+6k−24=0$$ has only one real root (the discriminant being negative).

Using the hyperbolic method for  one real  root, we have
$$k=\frac{1}{8} \left(1+2 \sqrt{15} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{149}{3 \sqrt{15}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Now,
$$a=\frac 3 4 k \quad \implies \quad a=\frac{3}{32} \left(1+2 \sqrt{15} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{149}{3 \sqrt{15}}\right)\right)\right)$$
$$b=-\frac{3 }{8}k^2 \quad \implies \quad b=-\frac{3}{512} \left(1+2 \sqrt{15} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{149}{3 \sqrt{15}}\right)\right)\right)^2$$